# Text in the TextField disappears when keyboard is removed

Tags: flutter

Text entered in my `TextField` widget disappears when I remove the keyboard from the view.

There are two `TextField`'s, title and description. The above problem only occurs for the title but not with the description.

Here's the relevant excerpt from the `build` method:

@override

```dart
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            _note = widget._note; // This is coming from StatefulWidget Class above
            TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.title;
            _titleController.text = _note.title;
            _descriptionController.text = _note.description;

            return Scaffold(
                body: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        style: textStyle,
                        controller: _titleController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Title",
                            labelStyle: textStyle,
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        style: textStyle,
                        controller: _descriptionController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Description",
                            labelStyle: textStyle,
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
                      ),
                    ),  
           ...
          }
        }
```

Screenshots of [Keyboard shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTSmt.png) & [removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXz7l.png).

Comment: You will need to include your `_titleController` code in your question as `TextFields`'s do not show this behavior inherently.

Comment: Please add `_titleController` and `_descriptionController` code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This occurs because you are setting the text in your `build` method. This `build` method can get invoked at any time, e.g. when the keyboard is contracted because the UI needs to react to that.
This means that you should move this code to [`initState`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html):

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  _note = widget._note;
  _titleController.text = _note.title;
  _descriptionController.text = _note.description;
  super.initState();
}
```

`initState` is only called once when the your widget is inserted into the build tree.

I am not sure why this only happens with one of the `TextFields`'s. I assume that you are using the `TextController`'s somewhere else to set the `Note`'s content, which could cause this behavior.
Furthermore, you should probably avoid using a leading underscore `_` for `_note` in your `StatefulWidget` (`widget._note`) as you access it from your `State`.